# How do I troubleshoot caching

Tags: wordpress, caching

I'm having an issue with the caching of a WordPress site. I am getting inconsistent displays of the site. I have changed my DNS server from my ISP to Google and the site has no chaching. I've viewed the site on a different ISP and it is still inconsistent. My browser cache is set at 0 and I'm using "?" in the URL. Is there any way to determine where the caching is originating? The site is on a budget shared hosting account.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different web browser. That'll tell you if the cache is because of a plugin like W3 Total Cache or your browser's cache. Maybe try disabling all of your plugins and themes and see if that makes any difference. The DNS is very likely not going to make a lick of difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Firebug or Web-Kit Dev Tools for this.

1. You can more fully disable/enable browser cache conveniently
2. You can use the Net panel to see what is loading, how fast it is loading, and where it is loading from.